# Apache POI read excel xlsx with greek language

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-poi

There are a lot of topics how to read XLSX files and write to file and them work for me, but not for greek (just example) words. Excel looks like this:

```
srcid   city    county
00008   ΠΑΤΡΑ   ΑΧΑΪΑΣ
00008   ΠΑΛΛΗΝΗ ΑΤΤΙΚΗΣ
00008   ΠΑΤΡΑ   ΑΧΑΪΑΣ
```

When I read this, I get ???? where are cities and counties.
I tried different example: [ToCSV](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.java) , [XLSX2CSV](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java)

Something wrong with charset, but I dont know what.
I updated examples with UTF-8 encoding, but no luck.

I am using this dependencies:
    
        org.apache.poi
        poi
        3.9

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help. I can't find out what is wrong. Maybe something this system encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToCSV.saveCSVFile` uses a FileWriter, which uses the default platform encoding. Instead do:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(
        new FileOutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

(Then it is always UTF-8.)

Comment: Thanks @Joop_Eggen for quick answer. This worked. I feel so stupid right now. Thank again.